# Is there any water in a korban minchah?

Tags: passover, water, mincha-meal-offering, maseches-pesachim

The Maharal (Gevuros Hashem, ch. 48) proves that matzah ashirah is considered matzah from the fact that the korban minchah is called matzah even though it is made with oil. But in the continuation of his discussion, he says that obviously if there is no water in the matzah, it is not matzah at all, (because it cannot become chametz). Does a korban minchah have any water in it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> כל המנחות נילושות בפושרין, ומשמרן שלא יחמיצו.
>   "All the *menahoth* are kneaded with lukewarm water..."

מנחות ה,ב, Tractate Menahoth 5:2

This is codified in the Rambam as well (מעשי הקרבנות [יב:כא](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=8&hilchos=45&perek=12&halocha=21&hilite=)):

> כל המנחות הנאפות נילושות בפושרין ומשמרן שלא יחמיצו. הואיל ולישתן ואפייתן בפנים בעזרה אנשי פנים זריזין הן:

Comment: Hello @loewian, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! You could make your answer even more useful by translating and explaining your source, as we try to cater to the largest audience possible. Thanks, and I hope to see you around the site!

Answer (score 1):

These [class notes](http://www.hinnuch.com/season-one/class-22-1/class-notes---class-22) are on the Sefer HaChinuch Mitzvah #116.

> It requires the cohanim to bring minchah sacrifices according to the
>   required procedures.  M’nachot were sacrifices consisting of flour,
>   sometimes with oil and sometimes with water, and sometimes with
>   frankincense.
>
> 1. For a minchah al machvat, water is added and the dough is kneaded.   The person doing the kneading needs to keep kneading it so
>      that it does not become hametz.   The dough is formed into cakes and
>      placed on a pan that looks something like a cupcake pan turned upside
>      down.  The cakes are then placed over heat so that the cakes fry in
>      the oil.
> 2. A minchah al marcheshet is the same as a minchah al machvat except that the cupcake pan is right side up and the dough is placed
>      in the cups.
> 3. “Challot” are m’nachot baked in an oven.  All of the necessary oil is added during the first mixing process.  Then water is added and
>      the dough is kneaded.  The cakes are baked on the bottom of the oven.
> 4. To make “r’kikin” the flour is mixed with the little bit of oil added at first and with water.  Then it is kneaded, made into
>      cakes and baked.  After that, the rest of the oil is spread on top of
>      the cakes.

So, yes some types of korban minchah have water in them.

Comment: Doesn't look like the Sefer ha-Chinnukh says anything about water but may be so nonetheless http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01644_part_116.html